# pip install Python-linkedin issues

Tags: python, installation, linkedin-api, pip

Help!

Big time noob question here. I'm trying to figure out the python world and started by creating a virtual environment. Everything looks alright - didn't get any errors.

Though, when I try to install this http://ozgur.github.io/python-linkedin/ wrapper I get an error:

(venv)user@ip-10-154-150-219:~/bin$ pip install python-linkedin
Downloading/unpacking python-linkedin
  Running setup.py egg_info for package python-linkedin
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 16, in 
      File "/home/user/Envs/venv/build/python-linkedin/setup.py", line 12, in 
        with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**), 'README.rst')) as readme:
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/Envs/venv/build/python-linkedin/README.rst'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 16, in

File "/home/user/Envs/venv/build/python-linkedin/setup.py", line 12, in

```
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'README.rst')) as readme:
```

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/Envs/venv/build/python-linkedin/README.rst'

---

Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/user/Envs/venv/build/python-linkedin

Any and all help would be very appreciated - I'm sure its something really stupid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is not your fault. I took a quick glance at the current master tree of `python-linkedin` repository and it seems that README.rst file is missing from the distribution the author uploaded to PyPi.

I'm filing a bug and attaching a pull request so hopefully you'll be able to install it soon.

Edit: there's already an [issue raised](https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin/issues/19), I'm just going to attach a pull request then: https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin/pull/20

Edit: attach a method on how to make it install for you, and still be able to uninstall and/or update through `pip` if you want to.

1. Go to my fork for now: https://github.com/woozyking/python-linkedin
2. `git clone https://github.com/woozyking/python-linkedin.git` or download the zip
3. (Extract zip and) go into `python-linkedin` folder.
4. Do `python setup.py sdist`
5. Go into `python-linkedin/dist`, and do `pip install python-linkedin-2.0.[OS_dependent]` (normally you should only get one file, so just tab for auto suggestion for the distribution archive file name.

And you're done.

Edit: my pull request has been merged, it's believed to be updated on PyPi as well, give it a shot again :)